# minimal distance of a vector to an element of a rectangular box

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity

Consider a known rectangular box $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ a vector.
I would like to determine an inexpensive way to compute $y^* \in \Omega$, such that $$y^* = \arg \min_{y \in \Omega}{(||x-y||_2)}$$.

I need to compute it with $d$ potentially very large, is there a way to do it with a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ ? Any computation method is welcome anyway.

First, we can write the box as a cartesian product of intervals, $\prod_{i=1}^d [a_i, b_i]$. 
We also write $x = (x_1, ..,x_d)$ and $y^* = (y^*_1, ..., y^*_d) $.
My first intuition, looking at a 2d rectangle, is that if $x_i \in [a_i,b_i]$ then $y_i^* = x_i$.

When $x_i \notin [a_i,b_i]$ then $y_i^* = \arg \min_{a_i,b_i}{(||x_i-a_i||_2,||x_i-b_i||_2)}$.

Does that sounds correct to you ? It's only an intuition and I did not work on a proof.

Comment: Ok I'll change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is sound. Can you see why?

**Hint:** Observe that minimizing ${\lVert x - y\rVert}_2$ is the same as minimizing ${\lVert x - y\rVert}_2^2$.
In this format, it should be easier to see you can minimize the square difference of each coordinate independently.

Comment: thanks I see the independence of each coordinate now